# Live edit of language file in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I need to change one string in translation file over front-end part of the site. Is there a method that can change that(because language files are not part of the database)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the file in the server (by SSH or uploading with FTP) or you can edit locally, push with Git and pull in the server.

Comment: the user needs to be able to change it not I

Comment: Then you have to put it in a database and make a CRUD to manage it.